# Bundle Part of the Java Virtual Machine into a Project

Tags: java, jvm

Is it possible to write a Java program that can run without Java installed? I know that this is a silly question, but the reason I ask is because I would like to create a Java program that has the parts of the Java Virtual Machine that is uses bundled into it to remove the dependency that it would have on needing a computer on which Java is installed. Is this possible, and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: That's effectively what the JRE is.

Comment: @HotLicks But you need the JRE on a computer to run a Java program. I am talking about perhaps bundling a portion of the JRE into the program so that it can run on computers on which it has not been installed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a way to construct an executable JAR that contains the JRE.  Of course, the problem is that what you end up with is quite large, and will be very slow starting.  I don't believe it's done very often.

Comment: I want to do it mostly as an option for a program that I am making. I want to give users the option to use one without the JRE bundled in it, but for users that do not know how to install the JRE, I want to give them the option to get it as a part of the program.

Comment: @HotLicks While I can't say if it's done very often, Apple's App Store requires that any Java "App" be bundled with the JRE...FYI ;)

Comment: If I was you, I'd have a look around, some of the installers allow you to download the JRE if it's not installed, it might be possible to tell from where the should get it (ie from within the bundle)...All you could simply use a native installer package...What we're working towards is having the "jre" bundled directly within our application and having our launchers use it as a prefence

Comment: @MadProgrammer While I agree with your recommended solution, there is a reason that I want to bundle the JRE with the jar file. My reason is that I know someone that insists on using the program that I wrote, but at the same time, they don't want to have the JRE on their computer. I have told them that that is impossible, but they won't take no for answer. I figured that I could trick them by bundling the JRE into the jar file.

Comment: @DavidB it "might" be possible to wrap the JRE, application Jars into a single native executable

Comment: Have you considered Java Web Start? Solves this problem and several others too.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you mean:

- It is possible to write an application installer for a Java app that will also install an embedded JRE.  One caveat is that the Oracle Java binary license does not permit you to embed a *partial* JRE.  It is the whole JRE ... or nothing.
- Under some circumstances, it is possible to compile Java to native code that can be executed without an Oracle JRE installation.

However, there are serious (IMO) drawbacks to both of these approaches.

- The embedded JRE approach can lead to a proliferation of JRE installations on the user's machine, and issues with timely application of Java security patches.
- There are serious limitations to what you can do with the compile-to-native-code approach.  For instance the GCJ compiler / runtime only supports Java 1.4 with some 1.5 additions ...

All in all, it is better to require the user to download the latest JRE from a reputable source and install it in the standard place.  Note that this is a simple procedure for all but the most technophobic users provided they have admin rights.  (And if they don't, they can't install your software either ...)

Comment: So it is possible then? I understand that it is not practical, but I was wondering if it was possible.

Comment: It is definitely possible.

Comment: Package a JRE with your app, write an installer that installs both at the same time.  One benefit of this is you know exactly what JRE you are running against and can support it.  On the flipside, you are running against a single JRE and need to support it.

Comment: @Pedantic - I don't see that as a flipside.  You are going to need to support running against at least one version of Java (JRE) anyway.  IMO, the problem of security patching is far more important.

Comment: @Stephen C I agree with your comment and the "flipside" of the approach I mentioned is that you'll have to manage the JRE used against the app you're deploying.  If we could rely on users to install and maintain a JRE in a singular, predictable place I wouldn't have offered the advice in my comment.  Also bear in mind Program Files (x86) vs. Program Files on MS(tm) platforms for folks who have to deal with 64-bit systems and that's just annoying.

Comment: *"If we could rely on users to install and maintain a JRE in a singular, predictable place I wouldn't have offered the advice in my comment."* - We can't stop the user from doing something stupid, but generally speaking they don't override default installation locations.  And a decent MS windows sysadmin should have no problem knowing where the *usual* installation locations for Java are.  The problems arise when users are installing stuff that the sysadmins are not aware of, and the installers are dropping "embedded" JRE's in unexpected places.

Comment: Define a "decent" windows sysadmin.  I dare you.  :)

Jokes aside, as a developer I haven't been able to rely on Sun/Oracle to unify this.  As a release engineer, I'd rather deploy my own JRE (even thought it bloats the user's system) because I _know_ what JRE the application is running against.  As a system user I _hate_ the Oracle/Java update mechanism because it prompts me for admin privs.  Most of my enterprise users cannot update their JRE.

Comment: @Pedantic - I guess it all depends on who is responsible for doing what for who.  And who is responsible for implementing system security / patching in your organization.  I concur that Oracle / Sun have been singularly unhelpful.  Take a look at their idea of supporting Linux ... for instance.  However, even in the context of that, there is a definite default place where an Oracle JRE of a particular flavour will be installed.

Comment: @Pedantic - *"As a system user I hate the Oracle/Java update mechanism because it prompts me for admin privs. Most of my enterprise users cannot update their JRE."*.  Well admin privileges *are* required to install software on modern Windows, and that is probably a good thing.  And there is probably a good reason for your enterprise users not having admin rights.  But that's not your concern.  That's between them and *their* sysadmins / security folks.

Comment: @Pedantic So how can I can embed the Java Runtime Environment into an executable jar? For a program that I am working on now, I am going to offer two builds: one for users with Java already installed and one for users that do not have Java installed and do not want to install it.

Comment: @DavidB - I'd advise you to look for a Java installer builder product.  There are both commercial and free products out there ... just a Google away.  Any decent installer builder will be able to generate an installer with an embedded JRE.  (But see my Answer.  I think that embedded JREs are a bad idea ...)

Comment: @StephenC I totally agree with you that embedded JREs are a terrible idea, but some of user base consists of people that do not want to install Java but insist on using a Java program without it. Here's an installer maker that I found: http://izpack.org/

Comment: @DavidB - There's a good Wikipedia resource ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Comment: @DavidB a JRE adds about 75MB of bloat to your package (install it in a subdirectory below your own code).  Reference it using relative paths in whatever startup scripts or code you use.  There are installation packages that streamline this but the general way this is handled is to rely on the user's system-wide JRE which may or may not be okay for your needs.

Comment: @Pedantic My program launcher is Java program itself. Could I do something like that?

Comment: @DavidB what do you mean, like an executable jar?  I don't know your environment or your setup so I can't say for certain.

Comment: @DavidB - If you want your installer to run without a pre-existing Java installation, it has to be (at least in part) implemented in something other than Java.  A typical approach is to make it a highly portable / robust shell script which has an encoded "payload" attached containing the JRE, your application code, and the code of the installer.  However you do it, you will need to use a different approach for Linux and Windows.  A decent installer generator takes care of all of this for you.

Comment: @StephenC Okay, thanks. Could you recommend a good installation generator, or should I pick something from the existing list that was given to me from WikiPedia?